# Boolean logic in a GROUP BY part of a MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently have a customers table that has duplicate customers in it.  I want to select a unique list of customers, with no duplicates of home phone OR cell phone.

So, if any customer has the same home phone or cell phone as another customer then, I want to not return that customer from the query.

One caveat -- if homephone or cellphone is empty, then I obviously do not want to count it in the anti-duplicate logic, because some customers only have a homephone, or only have a cellphone.

Here is the current query that I have, which returns unique rows for homephone AND cellphone.

```
SELECT id, firstname, lastname, homephone, cellphone, city, state, zip, 
country, FROM customers WHERE (homephone != "" OR cellphone != "")
GROUP BY homephone, cellphone
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: If two customers have the same home phone number, how do you decide which one to discard?

Comment: @ruakh any of them would be fine, if they have the same home phone number

Comment: @danihp my query does not return the expected result

Comment: So if two customers have phone = 1234 but cell numbers = 5678 and 8765, you still need one row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to funnel all phone numbers into the *one* evaluation and sort/group by that.

Try this:

```
SELECT id, firstname, lastname, homephone, cellphone, city, state, zip, country
FROM customers
WHERE homephone != '' OR cellphone != ''
GROUP BY case when homephone = '' then cellphone else homephone end
```

It will get the first row found for every unique  value of "homephone, but if blank then cellphone"

Answer (score 1):

If two customers have the same non-empty home-phone or the same non-empty cell-phone, then this query will discard the one with the greater `id`:

```
SELECT id, firstname, ...
  FROM customers c1
 WHERE (c1.homephone != '' OR c1.cellphone != '')
   AND (    c1.homephone = ''
         OR NOT EXISTS
             ( SELECT 1
                 FROM customers c2
                WHERE c2.id < c1.id
                  AND c2.homephone = c1.homephone
             )
       )
   AND (    c1.cellphone = ''
         OR NOT EXISTS
             ( SELECT 1
                 FROM customers c3
                WHERE c3.id < c1.id
                  AND c3.cellphone = c1.cellphone
             )
       )
;
```

Note that this can give pathological results if it happens that customer X has the same *home* phone as customer Y but the same *cell* phone as customer Z.

Comment: +1, but be careful, you should change `customers.homephone` by `c1.homephone` at the same with `cellphone` ;)

Comment: @danihp: Sorry, but I'm not sure what you mean. If there's a problem with the query I gave, then please feel free to edit my answer to fix it. :-)

Comment: oh! Your answer now is right! and without edit!?!?! How could it be?

Comment: @danihp: If you edit a question or answer within five minutes after posting it, or within five minutes after editing it, the new edit is subsumed into what was there before, rather than showing up as an edit. I don't really remember the details, but I must have edited my answer right after you saw it, and then you commented right after that without seeing that it had changed.